# MongoDB is not showing collections when creating through Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

So I had a directory named `data`, I ran `mongod --dbpath path_to_data`, it worked and gave me a port. I created a Node JS application, inserted some dummies data to the MongoDB through the same port using the `mongodb` package. When I ran the app, it worked fine. I even had it printed out through `MongoClient find()` method. However, when I opened the `mongo` shell and typed `show collections`, there wasn't any collections that showed up.

Comment: You sure you in the correct database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Apparently, if you set up the database path as `mongod --dbpath something/another/projectfolder/data`, then at your node js file, connect using the path `something/another/projectfolder`. Don't include the `data` there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same thing happen to me when I first installed Mongo on my Windows 10 machine. I'm not sure exactly what caused the problem, but it cleared up after I uninstalled MongoDB and then [reinstalled it as a Windows Service](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#manually-create-a-windows-service-for-mongodb-community-edition).